# How to draw networks in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, graph-theory, graph-visualization

I have a matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `mx2` that contains in each row the labels of two nodes showing a direct link in a network, e.g.:

if the network has `4` nodes the matrix `A` could be `A=[1 2; 1 3; 2 1; 2 4; 3 2; 4 1; 4 2]`, where the first row means that there is a link from `1` to `2`, the second row means that there is a link from `1` to `3`, etc.

Could you suggest me a quick way to draw the network from A?

Comment: Do you have access to the bioinformatics toolbox?

Comment: Yes, I have access to it

Comment: In Matlab 2015b the function `graph` was introduced.

Comment: [similar question with a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27339909/2732801)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the links to be directional, and have the Bioinformatics toolbox, you can create a `biograph` object.  This also allows for labelling the nodes with identification strings if you so desire, see the help file. If not they'll be called "Node 1", "Node 2", etc.   You'll need to convert your list of links to an adjacency matrix - @RTL gave the `accumarray` version, you can also use sub2ind:

```
N = 4;
adj = zeros(N);
adj(sub2ind([N,N], A(:,1),A(:,2))) = 1;

bg = biograph(adj);  % make biograph object
dolayout(bg);   % automatically calculate positions for nodes
view(bg); % what it says on the tin
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = max(A(:)); %// number of nodes
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,n+1); %// the nodes will be on a circle
theta = theta(1:end-1);
x = cos(theta); %// x coordinates of nodes
y = sin(theta); %// y coordinates of nodes
plot(x, y, 'ro') %// plot nodes
hold on
plot(x(A).', y(A).', 'b-') %// plot edges
axis image
axis(1.2*[-1 1 -1 1])
set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add the direction of the link?

Comment: You could use `annotation` instead of `plot`. The problem is that `annotation` used normalized axis units, which is cumbersome

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution using builtin [`gplot`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/gplot.html) function

```
adj=accumarray(A,1)
n=size(adj,1); % number of nodes
coord=[cos((1:n).'*(2*pi/n)),sin((1:n).'*(2*pi/n))] % points on a circle for nodes
gplot(adj,coord)
```

for large networks the adjacency matrix can be generated as sparse with `accumarray(A,1,[],[],0,true)`

Answer (score 1):

MatLab > R2015b now have the [Graph and Network Algorithms](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graph-and-network-algorithms.html).

`A` is what you would call an edge list.

```
plot(digraph(A(:,1),A(:,2))
```

Will draw the network.

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested in Matgraph, Matlab toolbox for graph manipulation:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19218-matgraph