# How to plot graphs in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a problem with Matlab.
Do you know a function that plots graphs? I have a matrix that gives me information about its links and I have to draw some of them to connect the vertices.
I've tried using "gplot" but it doesn't work.
Thank you so much!

Comment: The basic function to plot graphs in Matlab is `plot(x,y)` but your question isn't precise enough to know what you want to plot exactly. If you need something more low level there's `line` as well.

Comment: I have to draw 33 vertices and I have to link them using the information given in a matrix. Let's give an example: element in position 12 is different from zero, so I put a link between vertices 1 and 2; element in position 13 is zero, so I put no link.

Comment: @user3818040 what is your input? Why is gplot not working?

Comment: My input is a matrix. Gplot doesn't give me the graph I want.

Comment: in this case you need to use the `line` function to draw each line separately because it doesn't seem to be something you can do with a regular plot function unless you change your data. A nice way is using NaNs to say you don't want this value to be plotted and make some "holes" in the continuous line you get from `plot`

Answer (score 1):

From your comments above, it sounds as if you are looking to plot a "Graph" in the sense of connections between nodes.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804335/how-to-draw-networks-in-matlab?rq=1) appears to contain several answers that are likely to be helpful to you.

If not,  please give a concrete example of your input and we can probably help you.