# how to dynamically visualize a graph in matlab

Tags: matlab, dynamic, graph, visualization

I'm studying the evolution of social networks and now i'm testing my algorithm on a small dataset using matlab. I'd like to add visualization feature. Simply, i'd like to view how my network grows or shrinks in small size. May I have this without making available the adjacency matrix of graph. e.g. my network in different timestamps is:
t1:  (1,2)  (3,4)  // there's link bw node 1 &2, also another link between node 3&4
t2: (1,2)  (2,3) (3,4)
t3: (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (5,6)

May I have simple graphical interface using built-in function without having to integrate different packages available e.g. complex network package tailored for matlab. since most of them require adjacency matrix and if I have to provide this matrix just for visualization purpose (not necessary for my algorithm).
Thanks in advance for any guidance

Comment: Do you want/can set the node positions, or should thy be positioned automatically? Did you try gplot?

Comment: The coordinates of nodes is not important to me, but as I see I have to provide coordinates for gplot and I think the result would not so satisfactory as mentioned in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27339909/how-to-automatically-create-coordinates-when-graphing-adjacency-matrix-using-mat". So, I think I have to use toolbox to take care of this arrangement for me..

Comment: If available check the `biograph`, it can position nodes automatically.